# Getting error on updating magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgrade, magento2.4

On updating Magento 2.4 from 2.3 it will be stopped after getting this error [image]

on installing that extension it gives me this error

[image]

Issue on setup:upgrade command

[image]

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute this command in magento

```
sudo composer install
```

Comment: Yes I have figured that out Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have another issue after updating and on running php bin/magento setup:upgrade it will and and struck after Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite': Updated a screenshot in question.

Comment: May be it takes a little while (setup upgrade).

Comment: Thanks for your response it will struck around from 5 min is there a way to check if the command is running .